# why React native doesn't push an option that allow developers customize default font? Is Overwriting render function a good choice?

Tags: react-native

1, I'm wondering why React native doesn't push an option that allow developers customize default font if it's a popular resonable need?
I've searched a number of posts and see some proposal solutions like: declares fontFamily every time we use Texts, declares common style and reuse, creates custom Text component to replace Text component from 'react-native', use theme provider and Text component from 'react-native-elements'... It says that a number of people needs this, but Text from 'react-native' hasn't supported this yet?

2, I search out a solution that overwrites render function of Text component (ex: https://github.com/Ajackster/react-native-global-props/blob/master/src/CustomFunctions/setCustomText.js) and consider where it's a good choice for this? is there any performance concern for it?

Comment: RN is just the platform, it's usually up to you to make your own business components. If that's not magical enough, then highjack the render function like you showed above. If RN did allow you to do something like `RNGlobals.setFontFamilyEverywhereOnText()`, it would just use the same method you showed above.

Comment: Overwriting render function is quite simple and effortless to do, but it makes me concern about the unofficial form and compatibility with future upgrades. Do you know whether it will affect to performance of the application or not?

Comment: Use it and see if you notice any difference. It looks like it will only add a single object manipulation.